# Define custom variables instead of setting them in a function invoked on each session startup

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, hikaricp

Function `f1()` is executed over a million times a day causing CPU spikes.

This function is invoked for every webpage, batch job etc. or we can say that if an application/batch job/etc. connects to the DB, then this function gets invoked first, which sets up the RLS parameters.

Example:

```sql
PERFORM set_config (namespace || '.'||attribute,value,false);
```

The function is lightweight and currently takes `2 ms` to set up the session variables as described above. Can these session variables be cached so that application can use it from cache instead of executing the function?

Here is my function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1() 
RETURNS character varying LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS $function$ 
DECLARE
   v_status boolean; 
BEGIN 
   return current_setting('ctx_vpd'||'.'||'ctx_vpd_fil'); 
   exception when undefined_object then return 'ERROR'; 
END;
$function$;
```

Comment: You can define [custom settings in the db config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html), then `alter...set` their defaults on system, db, and user level. How did you determine the `2ms` function exec time on each session startup is what's causing "CPU spikes" you refer to? Is that a cloud-managed db or are you able to configure it freely? What language/ORM/client library are you using? Some (or even most) of them let you configure the pool/connector to handle the setting initialisation.

Comment: Yeah, It shows in RDS performance as Insights and it also shows in pg_stat_statements as top SQL. The application is JAVA application and we don't use any third party  proxy/pool between application and DB. And we use hikari connection pool in JAVA application while connecting to DB

Comment: Just a thought. Is redis will help here?

Comment: No, it won't. Unless all you used that db for was storing key:value pairs as session settings. I'm inclined to assume it's a random question, but it might as well be a perfectly reasonable option considering the larger context and specifics of your app/system/stack, which I know too little about to understand how you imagine Redis would solve the problem, and what exactly you consider *the problem*.

Comment: Also, if your RLS relies on static, globally shared set of settings, I'd question whether such RLS policies are even justified. If there is some variability in them after all and you just need to initialise the settings, you can instead keep your "settings" as values in regular tables, queried based on `current_user` from within the policy. Since RLS policies support subqueries, `select coalesce(current_config('some_setting',true), default_setting_kept_in_a_table) from my_settings where usr=current_user;`. It all depends on what you're doing exactly and what you're using the RLS policies for.

Comment: It looks like [RDS *might* let you configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html) the settings on db-level, as long as their parameter groups don't just let you modify existing parameters, but also add your own, the way you would in a `postgresql.conf`. Hikari [lets you add `connectionInitSql`](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) to run the series of regular SQL `set` commands, not necessarily as a PL/pgSQL function or procedure, but that sounds like what you're doing already.

Comment: Also, [`PERFORM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html) suggests this routine (`function` or `procedure`) is in PL/pgSQL. You might see some performance improvement if you make it a function that's `language SQL immutable parallel safe` (as long as it [qualifies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html)): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E1NdBpz0).

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: @Ramnath You can speed that up about 6x if you just switch to `LANGUAGE SQL STABLE PARALLEL SAFE`, 10x if you go `IMMUTABLE`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jPpKlNAb).

Comment: @Ramnath If you only caught the exception and returned `ERROR` just to avoid handling it elsewhere, but you don't rely on the result being the value 'ERROR' in any case, you can even get rid of the `coalesce()` and let `current_setting(a, true)` *not raise* the exception in the first place.

Comment: Hi Zegarek : I've gone through demo., I just want to know what is select setseed(.42)?
What does it do? After seeing your demo, I ran PL Profiler on my function and as you said above PERFORM is taking time.
Sorry, I'm stupid to ask redis

Comment: I used it in the first demo to get repeatable results from `random()`. Functionally, it doesn’t contribute anything to the actual functions